# Grothendieck trace formula over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}[[t]]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $k=\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$, $S=\operatorname{Spec}(k[t])$, $F$ the Frobenius automorphism on $S$ and $\mathcal{E}$ a sheaf of modules over $X$ such that $\mathcal{E}_{0}$ is of finite type.

Grothendieck's trace formula says that
\begin{equation*}\sum_{s\in |S|^{F^{n}}}\operatorname{Trace}(F^{n},\mathcal{E}_{s})=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i+1}\operatorname{Trace}(F^{n},H^{i}_{c}(S,\mathcal{E}))\text{.}
\end{equation*}

I wonder what happens if I replace $k[t]$ with $k[[t]]$, namely $\mathbb F_{p^n}[[t]]$?

**What I have tried so far:** A naive approach would be to consider $k[[t]]$ as the inverse limit of the rings $k[t]/t^{m}$, but this fails. I guess the reason for this is that each of the rings $k[t]/t^{m}$ has a spectrum consisting of a single point (the generic point and the unique maximal ideal coincide), whereas $\operatorname{Spec}(k[[t]])$ has two points (the generic point and the maximal ideal are different).

**Question:** Can the Grothendieck trace formula be modified in such a way that it works on $\operatorname{Spec}(k[[t]])$?

Comment: What are the two points of $\operatorname{Spec}(k[[t]]/t^{m})$? The maximal ideal $(t)$ and...?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. $k[[t]]$ is what I meant.

Comment: What's your X??

Comment: @wkf In my case $X=S$.